# how to get the link through which app opens in deep linking in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to implement deep linking in my app but couldn't get the link by which my the app is open, I need the link because in link profile uid is written of the user

for deep linking in flutter app I added the intent filter with scheme and host in android manifest file and when i tap on the link my app opens from the Home Screen but I want to get the profile uid from the link and using this I want to show the user profile following is the code where I try to get the initial link with which my app opens

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future<void> initUniLinks()async{
      try{
        final initialLink = await getInitialLink();
        print("initialLink");
        AppUtils().showToast(initialLink.toString());
        print(initialLink);
      } on PlatformException {
        print('platfrom exception unilink');
      }
    }
//CALL THE FUNCTION
    initUniLinks();
    return const MaterialApp(
        home: SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the format of the link? Also, which package are you using for deep links? Perhaps you could include these informations in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've correctly added an intent filter with a scheme and host in your Android manifest file to handle deep linking in your app. However, it seems like you're having trouble retrieving the profile uid from the link that opens the app.

To get the profile uid from the initial link, you can use the 'getInitialLink()' function provided by the 'uni_links' package. This function returns a 'Future' that resolves to the initial link that opened the app.

Here's an updated version of your 'MyApp' class that retrieves the initial link and extracts the profile uid:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:uni_links/uni_links.dart';

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String? _profileUid;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initUniLinks();
  }

  Future<void> initUniLinks() async {
    try {
      final initialLink = await getInitialLink();
      setState(() {
        _profileUid = _extractProfileUid(initialLink);
      });
    } on PlatformException {
      print('Platform exception occurred while getting initial link.');
    }
  }

  String? _extractProfileUid(String? link) {
    if (link == null) {
      return null;
    }
    final uri = Uri.parse(link);
    if (uri.pathSegments.isEmpty) {
      return null;
    }
    final profileUid = uri.pathSegments.last;
    return profileUid;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: _profileUid != null
              ? Text('Profile UID: $_profileUid')
              : Text('No profile UID found.'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using uni links package and I used your code but I still don't get the link. actually I have to write the link on nfc tag when phone scans that nfc tag it opens the launcher with my app but when I open my app it don,t give me initial link  but give me error which is following
_Could not navigate to initial route.
The requested route name was: **"/card_id/b7d55055-5856-4cd3-816a-449f4a1cfb75"**
There was no corresponding route in the app, and therefore the initial route specified will be ignored and "/" will be used instead._
the text in bold is the part of my link @Mohammad Soban